# Hibernate query by EnumType fails with Oracle (but works with MySQL)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, enums

We have the following Java enum defined in Constants.java:

```
public enum ComponentType implements IsSerializable {
    NOC("NOC"),
    // other values not shown
    ;
}
```

We have an Component class that has a field of type ComponentType:

```
public class Component implements Serializable {    
    private ComponentType type = null;
    // other code not shown
}
```

We have a Component.hbm.xml Hibernate mapping file that maps the enum field to a column:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
    <class name="our.package.Component" table="Component">
        <property name="type" column="TYPE">
             <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                 <param name="enumClass">our.package.Constants$ComponentType</param>
                 <param name="type">12</param>
             </type>
         </property>
         <!-- other mappings not shown -->
      </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

We have a DAO with the following method to query any field for any value:

```
protected T loadByX(Class<T> entityClass, String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
    T result = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
        result = (T) session.createCriteria(entityClass).add(Restrictions.eq(fieldName, fieldValue)).uniqueResult();
        session.close();
    }
    catch (HibernateException he) {
        // code not shown
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then we have the following code that calls the DAO:

```
Component component = instanceOfComponentDao.loadByX(Component.class, "type", Constants.ComponentType.NOC);
if (component == null) {
    //
    // SECTION A
    //
}
```

This code all works when the database is MySQL.  In the COMPONENT table, there is one row with a type column having the value "NOC", and it gets returned by the call to loadByX() and the "SECTION A" code does not execute.

However, this code doesn't work when the database is Oracle 11.  The COMPONENT table has one row with a type column having the value "NOC", but a null value is being returned by the call to loadByX() because the "SECTION A" code gets executed.

Any idea what is wrong when using this code with Oracle?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using here? There are some issues with Hibernate&Oracle using some types of fields between 3.5-4.1. Details here in a blog post: [Link](http://marcinderylo.blogspot.com/2013/02/enums-hibernate-4-and-oracle-database.html) Oracle actually appears to not adhere to the JDBC 3.0 spec despite their claims.

Comment: We are using Hibernate 3.5.6.  I tried adding <param name="useNamed">true</param> to the mapping file but it didn't change anything.